# Getting error like DexArchiveBuilderException at build time

Tags: android, kotlin

I am getting following error at run time as well as build clean time

> Error:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: 
>       Failed to process F:\bkp\projectname\app\build\intermediates\transforms\instantRunSlicer\debug\9

[image]

Comment: people on the internet say that you should disable instant run to fix it

Comment: Thank's sir it's work for me...

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't face this problem, just tried to search for a solution. After disabling instant run the error had to change. SHow the new error mesasge. But please don't use screenshots, show it as text